# Properties of periodic functions

Tags: fourier-series

Let $f$ and $g$ be periodic functions of period $p$.  Then $af(x)+bf(x)$ with $a,b$ constants and $f(x)g(x)$ are both of period $p$

I'm not exactly sure how to prove these properties of periodic functions.  I think I may have proven the first one, but as I remarked, I'm not sure.

To prove the first one, $f(x)=f(x+p)$.  So $a f(x+p)+bg(x+p)=af(x)+bg(x)$.

Comment: I think you really meant $af(x)+bg(x)$, right?

Comment: No, $a$ is just in front of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same approach works for the other example:
$f(x+p)g(x+p)=f(x)g(x+p)=f(x)g(x)$. The first equality follows from the $p$-periodicity of $f$, the second from that of $g$.